# Divergence of a vector field in an orthogonal curvilinear coordinate system

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, vectors, vector-analysis

How would one go about proving the following result in $\mathbb R^3$ for the divergence of vector field $\vec F = F_i \hat e^i$ 
$$ \nabla \cdot {\mathbf  F} = \frac{1}{h_1 h_2 h_3} \left[\frac \partial {\partial q^1} (F_1 h_2 h_3) + \frac \partial {\partial q^2} (F_2 h_3 h_1) + \frac  {\partial }{\partial q^3} (F_3 h_1 h_2)\right]$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a heuristic argument.

The flux across an area element perpendicular to $\hat{e}^{1}$ is
\begin{align*}
F_{1}\left(h_{2}dq_{2}\right)\left(h_{3}dq_{3}\right) & =\left(F_{1}h_{2}h_{3}\right)dq_{2}dq_{3}.
\end{align*}
Thus, the differential of this flux, along $\hat{e}^{1}$-direction,
is 
\begin{align*}
\frac{\partial}{\partial q^{1}}\left(F_{1}h_{2}h_{3}\right)dq_{1}dq_{2}dq_{3},
\end{align*}
and so the volume density is
\begin{align*}
 & \frac{1}{\left(h_{1}dq_{1}\right)\left(h_{2}dq_{2}\right)\left(h_{3}dq_{3}\right)}\frac{\partial}{\partial q_{1}}\left(F_{1}h_{2}h_{3}\right)dq_{1}dq_{2}dq_{3}\\
= & \frac{1}{h_{1}h_{2}h_{3}}\frac{\partial}{\partial q^{1}}\left(F_{1}h_{2}h_{3}\right).
\end{align*}